# Cannot modify XML File with XmlDocument and FileStream in C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows

I was creating a small constructor of html pages and I was using XML

When I have to edit particular element in my xml , it did not work:

```
       private string current_element = "pole";

        private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlData = new XmlDocument();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(ConstructorEngine.global + "/FormData.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            xmlData.Load(fs);
            var body = xmlData.GetElementsByTagName("Body")[0];
           
            foreach (XmlNode child in body.ChildNodes)
            {
                if(child.Attributes["c_id"].Value == currentElement)
                {
                    
                    if(e.ChangedItem.Label == "Text")
                    {
                            child.InnerText = e.ChangedItem.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
```

No errors given , but file is not changing

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FormData>
  <title>Constructor 1</title>
  <Body xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" id="app" width="400" height="400">
    <Button position="absolute" c_id="New_Btn" top="331" left="3" width="75" height="50" background-color="white" color="black" font-size="8,25" font-family="[FontFamily: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif]" border="1" border-color="0">Changed Button</Button>
    <Text position="absolute" c_id="pole" top="433" left="157" width="100" height="50" background-color="white" color="black" font-size="8,25" font-family="[FontFamily: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif]" border="1px solid;" border-color="black">pole</Text>
  </Body>
  <footer id="footer">Created By Constructor 1</footer>
</FormData>
```

Answer (score 0):

`XmlDocument` doesn't retain a relationship to the originating file once loaded. To fix this situation:

- **Close** the original `FileStream` (ideally by loading the XmlDocument within a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) which implicitly closes and disposes at the completion of its scope. Declare the XmlDocument variable outside of this scope.
- Make your changes to the XmlDocument
- Call the XmlDocument's `Save` method. For your purposes, passing it the name of the file to save to should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks it is working , but not in that way that I am looking for , it is appending to a file rather than overwriting. How can I fix that?

Comment: When I am overwriting file, it just pastes new string to it rather than modifying exact place which I am pointing in the code. What could be a solution @Tom W

Comment: The [documentation for [`XmlDocument.Save(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Save_System_String_) says `If the specified file exists, this method overwrites it` - are you using this method? If so I'd have to create an  example to reproduce this issue because I trust that the documentation speaks the truth...

Comment: Of course I am using this , I read the docs. It is exactly overwrites it , but I do just several changes in the file like ```child.innerText = "Some String" ```, and instead of changing exactly this``` XmlNode ``` and letting other part of file without changes. It just deletes whole xml and pastes my ```"Some String"```

Comment: `InnerText` replaces all the content of the chosen node, including its attributes and child elements. To replace just the text content use `.Value` (I got this wrong too on my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement text = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Text").FirstOrDefault();
            text.Attribute("c_id").SetValue("abc");
        }
    }
}
```